# Error: Cannot find module '../lib/npm.js'

Tags: windows, npm

Brief context: I was using an older version of node but decided to upgrade node so I downloaded the .msi and installed it. Installation went normally, however npm stopped working and I get this error

[image: cmd.exe screenshot]

Here's a screenshot of PATH

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem exactly likes yours on my server(CentOS 6.8), and I solved it finally.
Though the OS are different, but hope it's helpful to you.
Here is my solution:

Delete the directory `node_modules`, and uninstall node and npm, then reinstall them.

Then you may fix the issue.